# Jquery Append Method Causes Overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

So I'm trying to use the append method to apply new divs after the user submits a form.  It works, however if the form is submitted again after the results have been sent, it appends another set of output.  I want it to just replace the output if they resubmit.  Is there any way around this? Here is my JS:

```
for(var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++){
        if(i === 0){
          $("div#outputRow").prepend("<div class='col-md-4' id='row1'>");
          $("div#row1").append(finalArray[i]);
          if (i === finalArray.length - 1 ){
            $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          }
        } else if (i > 0 && i < 30){
          $("div#row1").append(finalArray[i]);
          if (i === finalArray.length - 1){
            $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          }
        } else if (i === 30){
          $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          $("div#outputRow").append("<div class='col-md-4' id='row2'>");
          $("div#row2").append(finalArray[i]);
          if (i === finalArray.length - 1){
            $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          }
        } else if (i > 30 && i < 60){
          $("div#row2").append(finalArray[i]);
          if (i === finalArray.length - 1){
            $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          }
        } else if (i === 60){
          $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          $("div#outputRow").append("<div class='col-md-4' id='row3'>");
          $("div#row3").append(finalArray[i]);
          if (i === finalArray.length - 1){
            $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          }
        } else if (i > 60 && i < 90){
          $("div#row3").append(finalArray[i]);
          if (i === finalArray.length - 1){
            $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          }
        } else if (i === 90){
          $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          $("div#outputRow").append("<div class='col-md-4' id='row4'>");
          $("div#row4").append(finalArray[i]);
          if (i === finalArray.length - 1){
            $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          }
        } else if (i > 90 && i < 120){
          $("div#row4").append(finalArray[i]);
          if (i === finalArray.length - 1){
            $("div#outputRow").append("</div>");
          }
        }
      }
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link href="css/pingpong-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
      <script src="js/pingpong.js"></script>
      <title>Ping Pong</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Ping Pong</h1>
        <form id='pingpong'>
          <label for="enteredNumber">Please Enter A Number:
          <input type="text" id="enteredNumber"></input>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div class="row" id="outputRow">
          <ul id="outputList">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: code is not complete enough to figure out what you are trying to do, but I feel you are not using ``append`` correctly. most likely you have ``</div>`` in your finalArray elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#pingpong").submit(function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault();
   $("#outputRow").html('<ul id="outputList"></ul>');
   // ..other stuff
   // .. your FOR loop
  for(var i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++){
    // ... your code
  }
});
```

Reset the HTML of the outputRow on Form submission. This will clear the results that were previously submitted.